# problem sftp connection with rsa keys

Tags: ssh, rhel, sftp, key-authentication

I am on RHEL 6. I have a user Jack which doesn't have shell access but SFTP. With my own user, I have created an RSA key pair with `ssh-keygen` command for jack (the user). I have created `.ssh` folder under jack's home directory.Also I created the `authorized-keys` file containing the public key under `.ssh`.

```
[root@myserver jackhome]# ls -ld .ssh
    drwx------ 2 jack jack 4096 Dec 20 11:38 .ssh
[root@myserver jackhome]# ls -l .ssh
    -rw------- 1 jack jack 405 Dec 20 11:38 authorized_keys
[root@myserver jackhome]# ls -ld /opt/apps/FTP/jackhome
    drwxr-x--- 9 root jack 4096 Dec 20 11:37 /opt/apps/FTP/jackhome
```

But I cannot SFTP with the private key. But the connection with SFTP password works fine. I have tested the key pair by connecting through SFTP with my own user with the same authorized_keys file and `.ssh` folder in my home directory; it works just fine.

I am a bit confused. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I have change the jackhome's owner as jack instead of root and i lost sftp access even with password:

```
[root@myserver jackhome]# ls -ld /opt/apps/FTP/jackhome
   drwxr-x--- 9 jack jack 4096 Dec 20 11:37 /opt/apps/FTP/jackhome
```

**UPDATE-2**: I have the below setting in sshd_config file. And Jack belongs to the sftponly group. Might that be the reason that he is not able to connect with rsa key?

```
Match Group sftponly
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Comment: Look at the server's `/var/log/secure` log file for error messages logged when this user attempts to log in. There should be a message describing exactly why `sshd` is rejecting the authentication. Also, RHEL 6 has SELinux enabled by default: run `getenforce` to check. If it responds `enforcing` and  a user has their home directory in a non-default location, you may need to manually set appropriate SELinux labels to that user's home directory (`user_home_dir_t`) and its parent directory (`home_root_t`).

Comment: SELinux is disabled.

Comment: /var/log/secure log file doesn't show much. Dec 24 15:22:56 myserver sshd[26545]: Connection closed by 10.9.212.8

Comment: i have added the **sshd_config** file as well to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sftp w/ the `-v` flag and paste what you get here. Using the `-v` flag will raise the logging level (verbose).

Example:

`sftp -i /home/jack/.ssh/id_rsa -v jack@192.168.1.1`